# Solución a un código de una función sin referencia

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "dummy2.h"

int exit_code=0;
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int primero=atoi(argv[1]);
    int segundo=atoi(argv[2]);
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    fd[0]=dummy2_open( );
    for (int i=0; i<primero; ++i){
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid==0){
            execlp("./slave", "./slave", argv[2], (char *)NULL);
        }
    }
    int acum=0;
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)>0){
        int i=0;
        int rem=waitpid(-1, &exit_code, 0);

        if(rem==-1){
            printf("hi ha hagut un error al slave\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else{

            acum=rem+acum;
        }
    }
    dummy2_test(acum);

    sprintf(buffer, "Els fills han acabat\n");
    write(1, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    exit(0);
}
```

Después de compilarlo me aparece este mensaje de error:

```
/tmp/ccA6uqSF.o: En la función `main':
master.c:(.text+0x1d2): referencia a `dummy2_open' sin definir
master.c:(.text+0x2a0): referencia a `dummy2_test' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:4: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'master'
make: *** [master] Error 1
```

El contenido de `dummy2.h`:

```
// Function headers for MASTER process
int  dummy2_open( );
int  dummy2_test( int );

// Function headers for SLAVE process
void dummy2_init( char buff[], int );
int  dummy2_comp( char buff[], int );
void dummy2_exit( );
```

Y para compilarlo uso:

```
gcc master.c -o master -L -ldummy
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido de `"dummy2.h"`?

Comment: Deberías indicar el contenido de `dummy2.h` y de `master.c`. Lo ideal sería proporcionar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema. Elaborar dicho ejemplo mínimo permite que te ayudemos más eficazmente y también puede servir para que tu mismo encuentres el problema... lo que te permitirá aprender bastante.

Comment: @PolLinger los cambios referentes a la pregunta intenta incluirlos en la propia pregunta editando la misma.

Comment: @eferion obviamente `master.c` es el nombre del archivo que compila y `dummy_*` son funciones a las que tiene referencia en tiempo de compilación (gracias al archivo de cabecera) pero NO en tiempo de enlazado (por no compilar juntos los archivos o bien no enlazar el código objeto adecuado).

Comment: no lo entiendo, he puesto la pregunta porque en versiones anteriores lho he hecho asi i no mhe dado ningun problema, ademas que el .a i el .h estan el mismo directorio

Comment: Vale, tu error está en usar `-L` sin más, deberías usar `-L.` para decirle que use el directorio actual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el código está en otro archivo C diferente debes compilarlos juntos o bien enlazar el código objeto (si lo compilas a parte) o la biblioteca de funciones.

Ejemplo compilando todos los archivos juntos:

```
cc -o ejecutable master.c dummy2.c
```

Con eso se compilarán ambos y funcionará.

Si ya lo tienes compilado (has generado el código objeto con `cc -c dummy.c`) y sólo quieres enlazarlo, entonces añade el código objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
cc -o ejecutable master.c dummy2.o
```

Si has generado (o te han proporcionado) una biblioteca de funciones (la puedes generar tú mismo con el código objeto con `ar crs libdummy2.a dummy.o`), entonces debes usar:

```
cc -o ejecutable master.c libdummy2.a
```

Teniendo en cuenta tu última actualización, la manera exacta sería:

```
gcc master.c -o master -L. -ldummy2
```

Comment: a mi me han proporcionado una libreria libdummy2.a i el dummy2.h y con eso compilandolo como si fuera un archivo normal tendria que funcionar

Comment: Vale, tendrías que haber empezado por ahí ya que la librería debes enlazarla con el nombre de archivo correcto: `libdummy2.a` en vez de `dummy2.o` como te propuse.

Comment: Mira mi última actualización. Si quieres usar el comando `-l` debes usar como ruta `.` en la opción `-L`. He puesto en mi comentario cómo sería, pero ten en cuenta que he supuesto que tu biblioteca de funciones se llama `libdummy2.a`.